# Cannot read property 'chat' of undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have tried all written in FAQ  it helped me to avoid all problems I faced except

> (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chat' of undefined )

Here is my code:

```
[[

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        // Proxy created on the fly          
        var chat = $.connection.chat;

        // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it          
        chat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
            $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
        };


        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function() {
            $("#broadcast").click(function () {
                // Call the chat method on the server
                chat.server.send($('#msg').val());
            });
        });
    });
]]
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery included twice in your page?

Comment: @Ahmed Could you provide more details ? is it Javascript ?

Comment: You are going to have to post some code if you want people to help, I think.

Comment: the problem solved thanks to you all specially to @dfowler the problem solved when I deleted @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fact of helping, when you defining 'chat' did you use [[ , ]] double square brackets in your .js?

Comment: it's asp.net MVC4 project using signalR 
that error happens in my client-side code

Comment: According to your code, everything is correct. So the error comes from somewhere else. Since you are using MVC, did you use <script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script> instead of <script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: the problem solved thanks to you all specially to @dfowler 
the problem solved when I deleted @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")